# Can I have properties hidden from console.log?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have properties of an object `a` that do not show up when doing `console.log(a)`?

Comment: Quick answer - no :)

Comment: If you want to store extra properties for an object whilst not adding them to the object itself, you could use `WeakMap`s.

Comment: If you could, how would you figure out if the properties have the right values when debugging?

Comment: Well there is a method to hide your actual data container if you need a data hiding: `function Foo() { /*data holder*/ var data = 0; this.getData = function() { return data;}; this.setData = function(value) { data = value;}}` Here you declare a private member and two accessors.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167104/hidden-properties-of-document) which is the reason why I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

Not that I know of.

If you don't want it seen, **don't** log it.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167104/hidden-properties-of-document). Basically some methods of an object are not `console.log`ging.

Comment: @Randomblue: Are you sure `.get` is not a prototype function? I'm not sure how Node's logging algorithm exactly works, but I guess it does not list properties in the prototype chain, since that would be kind of spam if you just want to log an object's properties.

Comment: @pimvdb: Aha, that's probably it! Thanks a lot.